# Extract data from table by field name. Xpath, python

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, webdriverwait, expected-condition

I want to extract data from this page https://mbasic.facebook.com/kristina.layus
There is a table  "Places lived" with two rows

```
Current city --- Moscow, Russia
Home town    --- Saint Petersburg, Russia
```

I can extract data with help of full xpath (extracted data "Moscow, Russia"):

```
/html/body/div/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[4]/div/div/div[1]/div/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/div/a
```

But I want extract data with help of names in table. I tried this

```
//div[@id='living']//div[@title='Current City']//a/text()
```

But received error

```
NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//div[@id='living']//div[@title='Current City']//a/text()"}
  (Session info: chrome=84.0.4147.89)
```

**My code**

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

class FacebookParser:
    LOGIN_URL = 'https://www.facebook.com/login.php'

    def __init__(self, login, password):
        chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
        prefs = {"profile.default_content_setting_values.notifications": 2}
        chrome_options.add_experimental_option("prefs", prefs)

        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options)
        self.wait = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10)
        self.login(login, password)

    def login(self, login, password):
        self.driver.get(self.LOGIN_URL)

        # wait for the login page to load
        self.wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, "email")))

        self.driver.find_element_by_id('email').send_keys(login)
        self.driver.find_element_by_id('pass').send_keys(password)
        self.driver.find_element_by_id('loginbutton').click()
    
    def get_user_by_id(self, id):
        self.driver.get(BASIC_URL + 'profile.php?id=' + str(id))
        
    def get_user_by_url(self, url):
        self.driver.get(url)
    
    def find_element_by_xpath_safe(self, path):
        try:
            return parser.driver.find_element_by_xpath(path)
        except:
            return None

    def get_first_name(self):
        res = self.find_element_by_xpath_safe('//span/div/span/strong')
        if res:
            vec = res.text.split()
            if len(vec) > 0:
                return vec[0]
            else:
                print("Can't split {}".format(res.text))
        return ""

    def get_second_name(self):
        res = self.find_element_by_xpath_safe('//span/div/span/strong')
        if res:
            vec = res.text.split()
            if len(vec) > 1:
                return vec[1]
            else:
                print("Can't split {}".format(res.text))
        return ""
    
    def get_curr_city(self):
        res = self.find_element_by_xpath_safe('/html/body/div/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[4]/div/div/div[1]/div/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/div/a')
        if res:
            return res.text
        return ""
    
    def get_home_town(self):
        res = self.find_element_by_xpath_safe('/html/body/div/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[4]/div/div/div[2]/div/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/div/a')
        if res:
            return res.text
        return ""
        

#####################################
LOGIN = '----.com'
PASSWORD = '----'
BASIC_URL = 'https://mbasic.facebook.com/'
#####################################

parser = FacebookParser(login=LOGIN, password=PASSWORD)
parser.driver.get("https://mbasic.facebook.com/kristina.layus")


parser.driver.get("https://mbasic.facebook.com/kristina.layus")
print(parser.get_curr_city())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To print the text **Moscow, Russia** you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49775502/webdriverwait-not-working-as-expected/49775808#49775808) for the `visibility_of_element_located()` and you can use the following [xpath](/questions/tagged/xpath) based [Locator Strategy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Printing *Moscow, Russia*:

  ```
  driver.get('https://mbasic.facebook.com/kristina.layus')
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//span[text()='Current City']//following::td//a"))).text)
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

---

### References

You can find a couple of relevant discussions on [NoSuchElementException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47993443/selenium-selenium-common-exceptions-nosuchelementexception-when-using-chrome/47995294#47995294) in:

- [selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element while trying to click Next button with selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50315587/selenium-common-exceptions-nosuchelementexception-message-no-such-element-una/50315715#50315715)
- [selenium in python : NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53441658/selenium-in-python-nosuchelementexception-message-no-such-element-unable-to/53442511#53442511)

Comment: Thank you. Could you please explain. Why ```//span[text()='Gender']//following::td//a``` did not return gender string?

Comment: @swor The gender string `Female` isn't within `<a>` but within `<div>`. Change your xpath.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add following code between login (loginbutton.click()) and opening target page:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
WebDriverWait(wd, DELAY).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "mount_0_0")))
```

This code will wait till login process will be finished,only after that target page should be opened.

Also check your xpath expression: when investigating page source div element with `id="living"` can be found, but div with attribute `title="Current City"` is absent.